# Turn off JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

how can I turn off the first jframe after clicking a jbutton to open a second jframe? just like this.
this is what I want to happen in my GUI:

[image: What I want to happen]

Comment: myjframe.setVisible(false) ?

Comment: What did your search turn up? On Stack Overflow you are always expected to search before posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are talking about implementing a 'GlassPane'

A GlassPane is a technique where you place a new RootFrame layer over the existing components and use it to

- Absorb all of the mouse events to prevent them from interacting with the components
- Shade the UI to draw more attention to the other modal window or other frame

You can read about creating a [glasspane/rootpane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)
and there are plenty of [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/DemonstrateuseofGlassPane.htm) of its usage

Answer (score 0):

A Swing application should only contain a single JFrame.

For the child window you can use:

1. a `modal JDialog` for a complex window when you want full control over the components on the dialog.
2. a `JOptionPane` for a easy to use pre configured "confirm" dialog. See: [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for examples.

Comment: I can’t see it answers the question? No matter if you use a `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` for the secondary window, you may still want (or need) to hide the main window or mark it visibly as inaccessible. So to me the question remains.

Comment: @OleV.V. Agreed, it doesn't. The fact that the OP indicated they want a second JFrame indicates that they don't have much UI design experience. I gave the OP an alternative approach that many applications use for a "confirm" type dialog. The OP can choose an appropriate solution now that they have multiple options.